# When I added 3 API keys into .env file then one api does not work in React.js on console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

- I put all the above code into .env file of react.js project

```
const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
const SERVICE_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID;
const TEMPLATE_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID;
console.log(API_KEY,SERVICE_KEY,TEMPLATE_ID)
const Contact = () => {....
```

-When I console  I got only two values i.e. api_key and service_id, template_id is undefined why?

Comment: Did you try to restart the react project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could need to install [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

And require it on the top of your application

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Comment: if dotenv required then why  two environment are working and one is not working.